# Firebase Rules don't work

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am Developing an App where you live in a flat and have roommates, now I'm trying to disable access for all users that don't live in that flat.

Here are my Rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    // no access 
    ".read": "false",
    ".write": "false",
      "Users" : {
      "$userID" : {
        //read on User Folder for all Users 
        ".read" : "auth != null",
        //write only for the user itself 
        ".write" : "$userID === auth.uid"
      }
    },
    "Flat" : {
      "$flatID" : {
        //Flat (identified through flatID) can only be accessed, if you are a roommate 
        ".read" : "$flatID === root.child('Users').child(auth.uid).child('flatID').val()",
        ".write" : "$flatID === root.child('Users').child(auth.uid).child('flatID').val()"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My Database looks somewhat like this:

```
root
.Users 
..uID
...(data) 
...flatID : number 
.Flat 
..flatID 
...(data)
```

So the flatID of that User is stored in his "folder" at root/Users/uID/flatID, which I try to get here: `root.child('Users').child(auth.uid).child('flatID').val()` and then I check it with the "folder" flatID.

Now if I try to write any Data into the flat, I don't have the right permission, and I cannot find my error. 
The Users/userID rule is working fine

Thanks in advance :)

Edit:

The Data looks like this:

```
root 
_Flat 
__1 
___name : "asdf" 
__2
___(more Flats, for the Problem we only need one) 
_Users 
__F8XpTmxfIzYzrEY92alBOnx5eTO2 (Auth ID) 
___flatID : 1 
__nextUserID
___NextUserData
```

My Java Code to edit the flatname is:

```
fref.child("Flat").child(flatID).child("name").setValue(flatNameInput.getText().toString())
```

The `flatID` is a variable with the flatID for that user

Comment: Please edit your question to include the minimum exact code and JSON that are needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Are you sure your flatID is a number (Same type) in the Flat "folder" and in the users "folder" ?

Comment: Firebase only works with a JSON string, so all types here are string?

Comment: So I didn't find a Solution to this problem, but I found a workaround which is working for me, I read the flatID from a different place, so it seemed to be an Type-Error like @Pipkis said